How to flatten org-attach-id-dir?
By default org-attach-id-dir is "data/", a relative directory.
In that dir my attachments are organized like this:
.
├── 16
│   └── 263857-cff6-474c-bb67-482d642edf5b
│       └── clipboard-20241009T231309.webp
├── 17
│   └── 88557f-dea7-4065-89cb-30b2a4e7e71c
│       └── clipboard-20241008T152156.webp
                ...
└── e0
    └── c8c79f-535c-4c53-99b6-1049d522a27e
        ├── clipboard-20241009T171426.webp
        ├── clipboard-20241009T204558.webp
        └── clipboard-20241009T211312.webp

23 directories, 16 files

They are generated from images pasted by yank-media on Org-roam files.
How to make them flat, such that data/ just contains the images directly without any sub dir, given that the image names are already unique?

M-x customize-group org-attach and you can find there are two variables org-attach-preferred-new-method and org-attach-id-to-path-function-list control the directory.

Setting org-attach-preferred-new-method to dir will cause org-attach ask the attach directory if org entries property DIR is not set. (Tips: you can set the global properties through org-global-properties.)

;; Preferred way to attach to nodes without existing ID and DIR property.
;; 
;; This choice is used when adding attachments to nodes without ID
;; and DIR properties.
;; 
;; Allowed values are:
;; 
;; id         Create and use an ID parameter
;; dir        Create and use a DIR parameter
;; ask        Ask the user for input of which method to choose
;; nil        Prefer to not create a new parameter
;; 
;;            nil means that ID or DIR has to be created explicitly
;;            before attaching files.
(setq org-attach-preferred-new-method dir)


You can also write your own org-attach-id-to-path-function:

(defun org-attach-id-flat-folder-format (id) "")

(add-to-list 'org-attach-id-to-path-function-list 'org-attach-id-flat-folder-format)

